# C - Read non-alphabetic chars as word boundary

Tags: c, regex, string

I'm trying to parse in a text file, and add each distinct word into a hashtable, with the words as keys, and their frequencies as values. The problem is proving to be the reading part: the file is a very large file of "normal" text, in that it has punctuation and special characters. I want to treat all non-alphabetical chars read in as word-boundaries. I have something basic going with this:

```
char buffer[128];
while(fscanf(fp, "%127[A-Za-z]%*c", buffer) == 1) {
    printf("%s\n", buffer); 
    memset(buffer, 0, 128); 
}
```

However, that chokes whenever it actually hits a non-alphabetical char preceded by whitespace (e.g., "the,cat was (brown)" would be read in as "the cat was"). I know what the issue is with that code, but I'm not sure how to get around it. Would I be better off just reading in an entire line and doing the parsing manually? I'm trying `scanf` because I felt that this was a pretty good candidate for the mini-regex thing that you can do with the format string.

Comment: `"%127[A-Za-z]%*[^A-Za-z]"` As an easy fix.

Comment: Using `while (fscanf(fp, "%*[^A-Za-z]"), fscanf(fp, "%127[A-Za-z]", buffer) == 1 {` Nicely deals with the first letter group that may be preceded with non-letters.  `"%127[A-Za-z]%*[^A-Za-z]"` does not.  Both approaches deal well with last letter group that may optionally be followed with non-letters.

Comment: Nice use of the comma operator :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest use of `isalpha()`, `fgetc()` and a simple state-machine.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int AdamRead(FILE *inf, char *dest, size_t n) {
  int ch;
  do {
    ch = fgetc(inf);
    if (ch == EOF) return EOF;
  } while (!isalpha(ch));

  assert(n > 1);
  n--;  // save room for \0
  while (n-- > 0) {
    *dest++ = ch;
    ch = fgetc(inf);
    if (!isalpha(ch)) break;
  }

  ungetc(ch, inf);  // Add this is something else may need to parse `inf`.
  *dest = '\0';
  return 1;
}

char buffer[128];
while(AdamRead(fp, buffer, sizeof buffer) == 1) {
  printf("%s\n", buffer); 
}
```

Note: If you want to go the `"%127[A-Za-z]%*[^A-Za-z]"` route, code may need to start with a one-time `fscanf(fp, "*[^A-Za-z]");` to deal with leading non-letters.

Comment: Why do we need `ungetc(ch, inf);`? `ch` is a non-alphabetic character which would anyway be discarded in the next call of `AdamRead`.

Comment: @ajay `ungetc(ch, inf)` is useful here should a _different_ function get called after `AdamRead()` that would expect to start scanning the non-letters.

Comment: @ajay Also `ch` _may_ be a letter.  The while loop may have stopped due to `n` becoming 0.  OP's function definition is open concerning what to do when the buffer is filled.  By putting back this potential letter, it has the chance of being read on the next function call.

Comment: The function scanning non-letters then must be called first before `AdamRead` is called else the leading non-letters will be removed from the stream. Also, in the case of `ch` being a letter which would be the case if there's a token equal to or larger than `n` in length, the token would be broken down into `2` or more pieces which may not be desired. I think `n` should be one more than the largest token length then.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way apart from the one mentioned in the comment. I don't know if it's better though. You can read lines from the file using `fgets` and then tokenize the line using `strtok_r` POSIX function. Here, `r` means the function is reentrant which makes it thread-safe. However, you must know the maximum length a line can have in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100

// in main

char line[MAX_LEN];
char *token;
const char *delim = "!@#$%^&*";  // all special characters
char *saveptr;       // for strtok_r 
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fp) != NULL) {
    for(; ; line = NULL) {
        token = strtok_r(line, delim, &saveptr);
        if(token == NULL)
            break;
        else {
            // token is a string.
            // process it
        }   
    }    
}

fclose(fp);
```

`strtok_r` modifies its first argument `line`, so you should keep a copy of it if it needed for other purposes.